# How does EF know the name of the class viewforbaseentityset... with view generation

Tags: entity-framework

Using EF5.0 and view compilation, i can see it all working.
Im see from the call stack  the view gets called.
The edmx property metadata artifact processing is set as embed in assembly

This method below (constructor) gets called. But how did it know the name?
Can i have multiple models in 1 assembly ?
Im happy it works, but id like to know what is going on underneath.

Any ideas?

```
public ViewsForBaseEntitySetsFE35229A04DD6E5585E40F6CE4FBC33EE6C9199EBD58235921B21B951250FF67()
    {
        this.EdmEntityContainerName = "BosMasterEntities";
        this.StoreEntityContainerName = "BosMasterModelStoreContainer";
        this.HashOverMappingClosure = "0edb68dd82ba8436bcabb10d30d018482670a8944e1013c90d795d35afea1b8d";
        this.HashOverAllExtentViews = "d0d326d5289ea43aa6ea7854e053ba0bd410789e3196101e38bace646c0fa404";
        this.ViewCount = 34;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually missing two important pieces of information in the code snipped - the code looks more like this:

```
[assembly: System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewGenerationAttribute(typeof(Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews.ViewsForBaseEntitySets6EB2ED815B2C1EA5C534EACE1F3EA695AAF84C0704F820B6C583CE86EFE39C0A))]

namespace Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews
{    
    public sealed class ViewsForBaseEntitySets6EB2ED815B2C1EA5C534EACE1F3EA695AAF84C0704F820B6C583CE86EFE39C0A : System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewContainer
    {

        /// <Summary>
        /// The constructor stores the views for the extents and also the hash values generated based on the metadata and mapping closure and views.
        /// </Summary>
        public ViewsForBaseEntitySets6EB2ED815B2C1EA5C534EACE1F3EA695AAF84C0704F820B6C583CE86EFE39C0A()
        {
            this.EdmEntityContainerName = "Context";
            this.StoreEntityContainerName = "CodeFirstDatabase";
            this.HashOverMappingClosure = "565d1a0ab9083c0e3d54e4d636e9ea8ace70a69f415e728c42b1e687acf65932";
            this.HashOverAllExtentViews = "84db96d2d3c40ffdbcbf3ab1e49f50e068df40cd9e62f87416402f6eb3569da0";
            this.ViewCount = 2;
        }
        ...
```

Firstly, there is an assembly level attribute of type EntityViewGenerationAttribute. Only assemblies that have this attribute will be considered as ones that can contain views. If you look closely at the attribute you will see that this attribute has the type of the class that contains views. You can have multiple EntityViewGenerationAttribute in one assembly. Secondly, the class containing views is derived from EntityViewContainer. If the type specified in the EntityViewGenerationAttribute is not derived from EntityViewContainer EF will throw.

Comment: The explanation was in my code and I didnt know what the attribute did. Thanks Pawel.  `code` [assembly: System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewGenerationAttribute(typeof(Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews.ViewsForBaseEntitySets6EB2ED815B2C1EA5C534EACE1F3EA695AAF84C0704F820B6C583CE86EFE39C0A))] `code`